# Autocomplete in typescript of literal type and string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, literals

How can I create a type so that autocomplete works or you can enter any string? And is it possible?
`export type StateWords = | 'first' | 'second' | 'third' | string`

I couldn't do autofill.

Comment: If you really can enter any string, it won't autocomplete anything

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Intersect `string` with `{}`:

```
export type StateWords = | 'first' | 'second' | 'third' | string & {}
```

`Record<never, never>` can also work:

```
export type StateWords = | 'first' | 'second' | 'third' | string & Record<never, never>
```

These intersections trick TypeScript into thinking that it is a "different" string type that literal string types are not assignable to (and thus the union won't get reduced to only `string`).

See [ms/TS#29729](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729)

Comment: I prefer creating a `type SomeOtherString = string & NonNullable<unknown>` and then defining `type MyEnum = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz' | SomeOtherString`.